# Magic of Python 2 urllib2 library's read method

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

My program was supposed to scrape a bunch of webpages. We have a constant string and generated string, which are the same. But the text strings, which are code of each web page suddenly are not equal.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2

def generate_list_of_public_urls():
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://vk.com/wall-54530371_2")
    error = response.read()

    gen_str = "http://vk.com/wall-54530371_" + str(2)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(gen_str)
    html = response.read()
    print gen_str == "http://vk.com/wall-54530371_2"
    print error == html

generate_list_of_public_urls()
```

And output is:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Do you realise that the page could change? VK has the API, btw.

Comment: @vaultah But this page doesn't change.

Comment: Check the output. It *does* change.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the page does not change in layout, or even seemingly in content, look at the page source.

At the very least, there's a section of JavaScript that helps serve advertisements that has a timestamp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vk = {
  ads_rotate_interval: 120000,
  al: parseInt('3') || 4,
  id: 0,
  intnat: '1' ? true : false,
  host: 'vk.com',
  ...
  ts: 1404931575,
  pd: 0,
  pads: 1,
  time: [2014, 7, 9, 22, 46, 15]
}
```

As @vaultah pointed out in his comment, the page contents do change. If you're trying to scrape data, either use VK's API or be more specific and target specific divs on the page using something like BeautifulSoup to parse the content.